# Evaluate the total of completed jobs in a given month using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to develop a formula in excel to do the following:

### Problem

1. Take a total of a column based on the word Nov (if there is a column of 7 values and only 3 of them read "Nov" then 3 is the total)

   - I know that I can use countif to achieve this step of the process
2. Based on the 3 rows with Nov in them, check and see if the completed column has a "c" in it and total the completed amount for Nov

*In other words I need a total of completed jobs in November when my list spans all months.*

### Research

I was looking at H/VLookup, but that only applies to one row at a time if I understand and doesn't create a total.

It's kind of an "If this and this than that" scenario, but searching that gives me results that don't take me down the path I think I should be headed.

https://exceljet.net/formula/if-this-and-that for example

With that in mind, I tried

=IF(AND('2016 Current Clients Tracking'!C3:C276="Nov",'2016 Current Clients Tracking'!F3:F276="c"),"x","y")

1. where the values in C3:C276(Month) & F3:F276(Completed) are on a different sheet
2. x & y are the next formulas I would use

   - but I see that I have to put a value and not another formula (if I could I think it would be =COUNTIF('2016 Current Clients Tracking'!F3:F276,"c")

### Looks Like

[Visual of what it looks like and should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWire.png)

### Extra Musings

I also think a Pivot table might be close to what I need, but some searching around and playing with it has left more more confused than anything.

Any insights on how to make this happen are appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you're looking for a count of records based on 2 criteria.

A simple COUNTIFS should do the trick.

```
=COUNTIFS('2016 Current Clients Tracking'!C3:C276,"Nov",'2016 Current Clients Tracking'!F3:F276,"c")
```

That will give you the total completed jobs in November for "Call1"

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula. Please check the ranges as per your requirement.

**Booked**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('2016 Current Clients Tracking'!C3:C276="Nov"))
```

**Completed**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('2016 Current Clients Tracking'!C3:C276="Nov")*('2016 Current Clients Tracking'!F3:F276="c"))
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. What does the double dash do? Thank you for the help!

Comment: `('2016 Current Clients Tracking'!C3:C276="Nov")` gives you an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, `TRUE` where the cell matches "Nov". `--()` converts the array to numeric i.e. `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`